# Confusion on Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, itineraries

I got my tourist Italian Schengen visa (multiple entry) but in the last minute I am changing my first port of destination to Germany as we decided to go for a one day music festival in Düsseldorf.
Mostly I will be staying 5 to 6days in Germany and go to Italy afterwards. I will be staying in Italy for 13 to 14days.

Is it OK to do this and travel to Germany first instead of Italy with my tourist Italian Schengen visa?

Comment: The majority of your visit will be in Italy, though, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are fine as long as your main destination is Italy.

> If the applicant is planning to visit two or more Schengen countries, it is highly recommended to be applying for the visa at the embassy/consulate of the country you will be residing in for most of the travelling days, referred to as the main destination.

Since you are staying for the majority of the time in Italy, your first port of entry need not necessarily have to be Italy and arriving in Germany is totally fine.